# Regex match between if present

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a string with regex.
Here are examples of how it should work

Should get content between center tags.

```
<center>match this text, can contain anything<\center>
```

Should get all of the content after the center tag

```
<center>match this text, can contain anything
```

I tried using look positive lookahead etc but I wasn't able to get it work

```
(<center>)(.*)(?=<\/center>)
```

for example, this regex doesn't match all of the content if the closing tag is not present.
Any help would be so good. Thanks.

Comment: It is just `<center>(.*?)(?=<\/center>|$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! This never crossed my mind, I thought the answer would be easy but I didn't think of this for some reason.

Comment: Or `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`  when the tags are on different lines, since the `.` (dot) usually doe not match line break chars.

Comment: @BartKiers I'm using s tag to match ```.``` to match new lines. ty

Comment: @Sibyl, that's good!